# Is hanging beam a type of vertical members?

Tags: building-regulations, building

per [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joist)

> A joist is a horizontal structural member used in framing to span an open space, often between beams that subsequently transfer loads to **vertical member**s.

What does "vertical member" mean here? Is hanging beam a type of such vertical members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A beam is a Horizontal member**, it transfers the load to the vertical members such as wall studs or posts.

When you lay down on a bed or on the floor you are the horizontal position, When you are standing on your feet you are in the vertical position.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_and_horizontal)

Comment: I like the clarification of “standing” is vertical.

Answer (score 1):

Beams and joists span horizontally to transfer load to vertical members like posts and load-bearing studs, which eventually bear down on footings or slabs or otherwise down to the ground.